# Outlook 2003 Add-in won't load, but is in working order

Tags: c#, deployment, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I have created an Outlook add-in for 2003, 2007 & 2010.  The add-in works fine in 2007 and 2010, but is not loading correctly in 2003 on any machines, other than my own dev machine.  There are no code issues, as there are no errors shown in the load behaviour, and it is not a disabled item.  The add-in is also not shown in the list of COM Add-Ins.  This add-in has worked under 2003 previously.

Here's the strange part. I have a copy of the add-in from an earlier point in time, so does not contain some of the features of the full version.  This add-in loads correctly in 2003.  So as part of my testing, on a VM, I installed the earlier version (I'll call it **test**) and the current version which doesn't work (I'll call it **full**).  In the registry under HKCU > Software > Classes > CLSID > [[guid]] > InprocServer32, for the **test** version I changed the 'Manifest Location' and 'Manifest Name' keys to be the values of the **full** version.  I then ran Outlook, and the full version ran perfectly.

I can't see how the **full** add-in does not work under it's own registry settings, but works fine under **test**'s, and only on Outlook 2003.

Here's the basic info:

My dev setup is:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Outlook 2003 installed
- Running VS2008 for the Add-in project, but also use VS2010 for a satellite assembly.
- Set Security project is included and amended to allow multiple assemblies to have CASPol set.

The following pre-reqs are included in the setup project:

- .Net 2.0
- .Net 3.5SP1
- Office 2003 PIA (also 2007 & 2010 PIAs for 2007 & 2010 respectively)
- VSTOSE runtime
- Windows Installer 3.1

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, as I've spend nearly 4 days on this issue!

TIA.

---

**Update 1:**

As per @JoaoAngelo comments I checked the registry settings, and they are as follows:

HKCU > Software > Classes > CLSID > {add-in CLSID} > InprocServer32

```
 - (default) - '%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\8.0\AddinLoader.dll'
 - ManifestLocation - path to the containing folder
 - ManifestName - the .dll.manifest file name
 - ThreadingModel - 'Both'
```

HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Office > Outlook > Addins > MyAddin

```
 - (default) - not set
 - CommandLineSafe - '1'
 - Description - a string
 - FriendlyName - add-in ID
 - LoadBehavior - '3' (this never gets set to 2, which would indicate an issue)
 - Manifest - path to the .dll.manifest of the add-in assembly
 - Path - path to the containing folder
```

I also added the following under the latter, as per the [Deployment page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269007%28VS.80%29.aspx), but to no avail:

```
 - ManifestLocation 
 - ManifestName
```

**Update 2:**

As per 0xA3 comments; Under HKCR > MyAddin I have a CLSID key with a single string value:

```
(default) - {add-in CLSID}
```

The CLSID is the same as seen in HKCU > Software > Classes > CLSID and throughout the registry.

Comment: What's defined under HKCR -> MyAddin (i.e. under the prog id of the add-in; the same 'MyAddin' string that is used under HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Office > Outlook > Addins > MyAddin)

Comment: I updated the original post (Update 2).

Comment: [Edit] : I see this has been updated - removing comment. My problem is actually different than this, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to find the issue, it was registry related.

I originally planned to have separate add-ins for each version of Outlook, and as such my namespaces and naming conventions etc were:

- [Company].AddIns.Outlook2003
- [Company].AddIns.Outlook2007
- [Company].AddIns.Outlook2010

However, I managed to create the add-in to target all 3, so I renamed [Company].AddIns.Outlook2003 to be [Company].AddIns.Client.

I'd changed the registry settings for HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Office > Outlook > Addins > MyAddin, to reference the change described, but for some reason I didn't update it under HKCU > Software > Classes.

As soon as I changed the latter settings in VS, it worked!

For reference the changes were made in VS under the Setup Project, under View > Registry.

A bit annoying that this issue didn't appear under 2007/2010, as it may have been easier to track down.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done it already you should set the following environment variables to assist you in troubleshooting addin loading problems:

- `VSTO_LOGALERTS=1`
- `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0`

The first one will result in a *.log file being created in the directory containing the addin assemblies and the second will enable errors popups to be shown when your start the target application, in this case Outlook.

You also say, that in your dev box with Office 2003 the addin works correctly. Since Visual Studio automatically registers the addin in the dev box when you perform a build, you should make sure that you are creating all necessary registry keys in the setup. You can check the *Required Registry Entries* section in the following MSDN article to verify that you have the correct keys being created in setup:

[Deploying Application-Level Add-ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269007%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried logging alerts previously and they didn't do anything as I believe they only work if the add-in is loaded.  However, I will add them in again to double-check.  I also include my own internal logging, but this is obviously no use, as the add-in is not loaded.  I've also looked through the link you sent previously, but again, I'll double check it's all correct, thanks.  It does seem odd that the registry entries are OK for 2007 & 2010, but not 2003, though.

Comment: I set the alerts up, but as suspected, I get nothing back.  I've updated the initial post with findings from the Deploying Application-Level Add-ins link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to follow the troubleshooting steps described here:

> **[Hamed Ahmadi: My Office Addin Does Not Load!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haahmadi/archive/2010/05/26/my-vsto-add-in-does-not-load.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I've already been through those steps and non apply to my situation.  I've also gone through [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx), but again non of that really applies.  With regards to that link, I've enabled Fusion logs, but none appear under Outlook.exe, which also confirms to me that Outlook is simply not loading the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the addin hasn't been disabled by outlook for some reason? If you've installed it machine level (as opposed to user level) it won't show up in the Com add in's list in any event. Maybe try installing it as a per user add in (so it does show up in the list) and go from there?

Comment: It's not disabled, and is installed at user level.

Comment: @SteveA: Have you checked explicitly whether your add-in is in the list of hard disabled add-ins?

Comment: It's definitely not in disabled items.  If it were, I would also expect to see the LoadBehaviour registry setting to change from 3 to 2. This is why I suspect it's just not being loaded in the first place. Also, I know the code is sound, as per my original post, so it's definitely not going to be disabled.

Comment: Hard disabled doesn't mean that the load-behavior changes. Check the link in my answer to see how you can check whether your add-in is hard disabled.

Comment: I know how to check that the add-in is hard disabled.  The article you posted doesn't really apply to 2003 much anyway.  But yes, I know how to [check for hard disabling in 2003](http://imgur.com/51B8y).  As stated in my original post, the add-in is in working order, I know it's not an issue with the add-in code, which would cause a hard disable.  I believe it's a registry issue.